# maven-enforcer-plugin doesn't see pinned versions in parent pom

Tags: maven

I have a parent pom - in its own project for reusability - that configures the `maven-enforcer-plugin` to run:

```xml
<project ...>
  <!-- ... -->

  <groupId>org.example.common</groupId>
  <artifactId>common-parent</artifactId>
  <version>1</version>

  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
      <plugins>

        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
          <executions>
            <execution>
              <id>enforce-default-settings</id>
              <goals>
                <goal>enforce</goal>
              </goals>
              <configuration>
                <rules>
                  <requirePluginVersions><message>Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!</message></requirePluginVersions>
                  <dependencyConvergence />
                  <reactorModuleConvergence />
                </rules>
                <fail>true</fail>
              </configuration>
            </execution>
          </executions>
        </plugin>

        <!-- loads of version pinning of default maven plugins like the one below -->
        <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>3.1.0</version>
        </plugin>

      </plugins>
    </pluginManagement>
    <plugins>
      <!-- ... -->
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
      <!-- ... -->
    </plugins>
    <!-- ... -->
  </build>
  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

In my actual pom, I've got

```xml
<project ...>
  <!-- ... -->

  <parent>
    <groupId>org.example.common</groupId>
    <artifactId>common-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
  </parent>

  <groupId>org.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>project-x</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

  <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

when I run `mvn clean package` on the child pom, I get

```
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce (enforce-default-settings) @ project-x ---
[WARNING] Rule 2: org.apache.maven.plugins.enforcer.RequirePluginVersions failed with message:
Some plugins are missing valid versions:(LATEST RELEASE SNAPSHOT are not allowed )
ome plugins are missing valid versions:(LATEST RELEASE SNAPSHOT are not allowed )
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-compiler-plugin.         The version currently in use is 3.8.1
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin.         The version currently in use is 2.22.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-jar-plugin.      The version currently in use is 3.1.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin.    The version currently in use is 3.1.0
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-dependency-plugin.       The version currently in use is 3.1.1
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin.  The version currently in use is 2.5.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-source-plugin.   The version currently in use is 3.1.0
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-site-plugin.     The version currently in use is 3.8.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin.        The version currently in use is 3.1.0
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin.   The version currently in use is 2.8.2
org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin.         The version currently in use is 3.0.0-M2
Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  0.665 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2019-10-09T12:37:00+02:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-enforcer-plugin:3.0.0-M2:enforce (enforce-default-settings) on project project-x: Some Enforcer rules have failed. Look above for specific messages explaining why the rule failed. -> [Help 1]
```

Running `mvn clean package` on the parent pom works as expected.

although when I run `mvn versions:display-plugin-updates` on the child-pom, I get:

```
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7:display-plugin-updates (default-cli) @ project-x ---
[INFO]
[INFO] All plugins with a version specified are using the latest versions.
[INFO]
[INFO] All plugins have a version specified.
[INFO]
[INFO] Project inherits minimum Maven version as: 3.5.0
[INFO] Plugins require minimum Maven version of: null
[INFO]
[INFO] No plugins require a newer version of Maven than specified by the pom.
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

When I *remove* the version-pinning from the parent pom. I *don't* get warnings when building the parent pom. Also, the versions plugin on the child pom reports:

```xml
[INFO] --- versions-maven-plugin:2.7:display-plugin-updates (default-cli) @ project-x ---
[INFO]
[INFO] All plugins with a version specified are using the latest versions.
[INFO]
[WARNING] The following plugins do not have their version specified:
[WARNING]   maven-jar-plugin ........................ (from super-pom) 3.1.2
```

So I'm proper confused about this. I thought I did the right thing by pinning the versions in the parent pom's dependencyManagement?

I also don't understand why the enforcer doesn't seem to work on the parent pom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

while a "configuration" setup is usually safe to place in the reference of a plugin in the plugin management tree, its execution is not.

Update your pom as follow and share the enforcer execution with inherited artifacts:

```
<project ...>
    <!-- ... -->
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <!-- ... -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>3.0.0-M2</version>
                </plugin>
                <!-- ... -->
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
                <!-- ... -->
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-enforcer-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <id>enforce-default-settings</id>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>enforce</goal>
                            </goals>
                            <configuration>
                                <rules>
                                    <requirePluginVersions><message>Best Practice is to always define plugin versions!</message></requirePluginVersions>
                                    <dependencyConvergence />
                                    <reactorModuleConvergence />
                                </rules>
                                <fail>true</fail>
                            </configuration>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
                <!-- ... -->
        </plugins>
        <!-- ... -->
    </build>
    <!-- ... -->
</project>
```

Note: you could certainly move the `<configuration>` part in the plugin management tree, but there are no added value in the current case to do so.

Comment: Thank you! I was going crazy . This solved all my issues :) and even better furthered my understanding of maven :)

Answer (score 3):

It might be issue with enforcer plugin release 3.0.0-M2 - see https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MENFORCER-306. Fixed in 3.0.0-M3